# How to hide pair and connect system dialog in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect the BLE device from my android app. it's working fine below android 11 but on Google pixel 4a showing system connect and paired dialog while pairing.

I want to hide it programmatically.

Added dialog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ogYF.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to pair?

Comment: yes, without user interaction. It's working for other devices but a facing an issue on Google pixel 4a. Appearing pair and connect system dialog

Comment: What pairing method are you using? I believe there should be no dialog if Just Works is used

Comment: I have added a dialog image.

Comment: It might help to show how you're pairing it in code